# Is a particular bund/embankment geometry more stable than others?

Tags: structural-engineering, geotechnical-engineering, structural-analysis

I am interested in  structural stability of earthen bunds. They are susceptible to being eroded by water. Let us assume I have a rice field that is surrounded on all four sides by earthen bunds. I have seen in my travels two geometries (shape of bunds). Some are rectangular and others are curved. Is there an objective way to analyze(mathematically I mean) which geometry would be more resistant to flooding i.e. rectangular(or square) vs. curved ? Water can hit the bund vertically from above(during precipitation) and/or horizontally (water from surrounding fields can flow towards a bund)

Here is an example of a rice field surrounded by bunds - [Earthen bunds](http://www.rkmp.co.in/content/bund-preparation-and-maintenance-for-water-management). 
This one is a bit curved but I have seen rectangular bunds as well.

Let us assume I have flat surface area.

Comment: Hi gansub: a typical x-sectional diagram of each bund type would make things clearer. When you mention rectangular & curved bunds, which part of the bund are you referring to, the top or the sides?

Comment: @Fred - I am referring to the overall shape. Some are elliptical and others have rectangular shape meaning they have two sides that is perpendicular to the ground and a top that is flat.

Comment: What is a "bund" I'm not familiar with that term. Is it similar to a levee or dike?

Comment: @hazzey - yes conceptually it is similar to a levee or dike. You can call them earthen embankments. The other term could be irrigation bund.

Comment: @hazzey - a photograph has been provided for illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bund stability will be affected by a number a factors:

- materials used to construct the bund
- compaction of the materials used
- the height of the bund
- the width of the bund
- shear strength of the material used to construct the bund
- the degree water saturation and depth of saturation
- whether any part of the bund is allowed to dry out completely
- the slope angle of the walls of the bund
- whether the bund has been protected by facing materials like hard
  stones that will absorb the energy of water hitting the bund
- the force of the water hitting the bund
- water drainage through the bund, if applicable

Unfortunately, there are no simple formulae that can be used to analyze slope or bund [stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_stability_analysis). The Swedish slip circle method or similar slicing methods would be the most appropriate techniques as these methods are used for slopes composed of soils and I'm assuming the bunds you are referring to are made of soil or a combination of soil and stones.

Comment: yes mostly clay.

Comment: the question is asked assuming materials used are identical, all heights are identical, width is identical, shear strength is same.  Should I edit my question to reflect your answer ?

Comment: how would the Swedish slip circle apply for a rectangular bund ?

Comment: when you get a chance can you add soil bioengineering tag ?